# Returning different types

Tags: c++, c++11

How could I (during runtime) decide which type to return from my function?
Is this possible at all?
I think it is but one can never be sure.

Comment: use polymorphism, e.g. wrap all the types in an interface (of course this will work only for user defined types), alternatively, you can just declare your method to return the `Object` type but that is not very elegant

Comment: In some limited cases, you could use a `union` (providing something discriminates it). In general, polymorphism is better.

Comment: @scibuff : you should post this as an answer.

Comment: #scibuff yes, but then (in Object case) I'm loosing type information and I need to know what type I'm returning.

Comment: You could use [Boost.any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/any.html).

Comment: #Basil how to go about with polymorphism, would you mind and give an example.

Comment: @smallB You don't lose the type information if you use a base class. As a last resort, you can always `dynamic_cast`.

Comment: @smallB: How can you know what type you're returning if the decision is delayed until run-time? That's the *definition* of not knowing what type you're returning.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There are multiple ways of addressing this issue. Personally, I try to only return different types if its a factory. Once that's done you should need to be returning anything.

Comment: Using a templated member function:

       template< typename T > 
       T GetValue()
       {
          return /* some value of type T */
       }

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use polymorphism

```
public interface MyType {
    public void doSomething();
}

public class A implements MyType {
    public void doSomething(){}
}

public class B implements MyType {
    public void doSomething(){}
}

public class MyClass {

    public MyType getData(){
        if ( /* some condition */ ){ return new A(); } 
        return new B();
    }

    public void test(){
        MyType o = this.getData();
        o.doSomething();
    }
}
```

then simply return type of `MyType` and call `doSomething()` directly on that object; ie you don't need to know whether the returned type is `A` or `B`. All you care about is that it implements `doSomething`. That is the beauty of polymorphism, i.e. no more ugly `is`, `getType`, `instanceOf` (Java), etc.

Comment: Misleading, it's a Java answer for a C++ question, not really an answer to the question, but a suggestion to an alternative that might not be applicable by the OP. Please look at the tags.

Comment: This example is Java and the question is about C++. Still, you can do basically the same thing in C++ if you only care about user defined types. What you can't do in C++ is fall back on returning `Object` since C++ doesn't automatically force all classes to inherit from a common root type.

Comment: @Jacobo are you serious??? who cares about the language, it's the same principle doesn't matter if it is c++, c#, java, php, ......

Comment: @scibuff: Well, you have to know both C++ and Java to properly translate the example. For instance, if you're inexperienced (and this question suggests so), you'd be likely to forget `virtual`. Furthermore, `MyType o = this.getData();` _slices_ the returned object in C++.

Comment: @scibuff I personally like your answer best. If it works for C++ I'm going to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @scibuff: Your answer assumes that the OP will know (a) C++, (b) Java, (c) any subtle difference that must be taken into consideration when translating it. Silly.

Answer (score 3):

If using Boost is an option, consider using [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant.html).

You can think of variant as `union` on steroids. It works with most C++ types and allows both compile-time and run-time polymorphism, but it does not require a common base class for types.
The main disadvantage is that it involves a serious amount of template metaprogramming, so it will put some load on the compiler.

Here's a short example to get the idea:

```
 typedef boost::variant<float, std::string> MyVariant;

 MyVariant GetInt() { return MyVariant(42); }
 MyVariant GetString() { return MyVariant("foo"); }

 MyVariant v;
 //run-time polymorphism:
 int number = boost::get<int>(v);   // this line may throw (basically a dynamic_cast)

 //compile time polymorphism:
 boost::apply_visitor(Visitor(), v);  
 // where Visitor is a functor overloading operator() for *all* types in the variant
```

A more light-weight alternative is Boost.Any, see [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html#variant.versus-any) for a comparison.

Comment: Boost.Any is a much more _heavy-weight_ alternative, as it involves type-erasure. But +1 for recommending Boost.Variant.

Comment: Light-weight was probably a bad choice of words. What I was trying to say is that Any is imho easier to learn and use than Variant. Sorry for the confusion.